# Getting individual ElementFinders from an ElementArrayFinder in a Page Object

Tags: protractor

In a separate Page Object file (not in the actual file with tests) I'm trying to do something like:

```
this.item0 = element.all(by.repeater('menu items')).get(0);
```

This won't work because the code is executed before the tests are run. I haven't found another way of doing this except to call get() in the test file (which I don't want to do). Is there a way to do this in the Page Object file?

Comment: Problem is that this wasn't supported until Jun 2 after [PR 889](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/889) that added "first(), last(), and get(index) are not executed immediately, allowing them to be placed in page objects"

Comment: See @Joel Kornbluh's answer, that's the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior often confuses people who are trying to write page objects.

Your locator will not be executed until you call a function on the elementFinder or the elementArrayFinder (see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md).

I usually use this pattern:

```
// Page object
MyView = function() {
  // This will not find elements until you call count(), get(), first(), etc.
  this.itemList = element.all(by.repeater('menu items'));
};
module.exports = new MyView();

// Test

// Require the page object at the top of the test file.
var myView = require('./my-view.js');

// Use the page object in the test.
it('should get first element', function() {
  myView.itemList.get(0).then(function(webElement) {
  })
});
```

Comment: I did something similar eventually. I just put the function in the page object itself.

Comment: @Andres D why does this not work inside a pg obj? this.arrayList.get(0).then(function (we) { we.click(); }); I get error - Failed: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. op was asking about calling the get() from within the PO not the test file.

Answer (score 1):

The following is from [source code for `ElementArrayFinder.get`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L274)

`/**
   * Get an element within the ElementArrayFinder by index. The index starts at 0.
   * This does not actually retrieve the underlying element.
   *
   ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get = function...`

So Apparently you should be able to call it from within the page object even before the elements are loaded.

Comment: This was fixed with [issue 889](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/889). so you will need to update your protractor module in order to get this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

yay, i'm not the only one using page objects ;)
i did the following:

```
var MyPage = function () {
  this.item0 = element.all(by.repeater('menu items')).get(0);
}
```

in my tests:

```
describe('MyPage:', function () {
    var myPage = new MyPage();
     // after this line navigate your browser to your page
     // then you can call myPage.item0, myPage.whatEver
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. What I ended up doing was saving the elementArrayFinder and then writing a function item0() that called get(0) on the finder.